# transitions causes blink after shake device jquery-mobile

Tags: html, ios5, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

I'm using iOs app, There is a Webview with jquery-Mobile, The problem occur when the device is shaked. Between page transitions looks a blink. If I don't shake the device blink not appear.

In landscape mode blink not appear, only in portrait mode.

My metas:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"> <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

I tried with:

```
-webkit-visibility:hidden
```

But this not resolve my problem...

Device: iPad iO5.

Comment: What is blinking? The whole screen, or elements on the screen? Or is something previously hidden becoming visible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly: When you shake the device, the page within the Webview is transitioned to a new one using jQuery mobile, and while it is transitioning the screen flickers/blinks and then after it is ok.

This could be a common issue when using `-webkit-transition`. You may simply need to force hardware acceleration. Hopefully you will be able to do this using `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`

Put that line into the CSS rule for the element with the `-webkit-transition` or on the parent.

Alternatively, the reason for the flickering can sometimes be an element pushed off the screen by CSS. For example, `text-indent: -9999px;` or negative margins on a child element. If removing these fixes it, and you can do it this way, it is a better solution than forcing hardware acceleration.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: isn't works but i think that it is a problem of UIWebView scale.